# Arranging dynamically generated Labels and aspx-Controls to look like a Dictionary without using table

Tags: asp.net, html, css, dictionary, stylesheet

I'd like to have a Page-Structure like the following:

```
Label1    |    (CheckBox or DropDown or TextBox etc.)<br>
Label2    |    (CheckBox or DropDown or TextBox etc.)<br>
Label3    |    (CheckBox or DropDown or TextBox etc.)
```

with this exact schema, considering that e.g. TextAreas take up more space whilst still making sure that Label and corresponding aspx-Control are on the same height.

I cannot know which Controls will appear since this is bound to the Parameters that are given to the form.

I was thinking about having a div for Labels and a div for Controls, arranging them next to each other and giving `.divLeft span` some kind of fixed height and margin that'd be appropriate for whatever Controls I put on the right side.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Why you don't want to use a Table? Table are not evil when it come to this kind of layout.

Comment: To be perfectly honest this is mostly about checking out what other approaches than tables there are for this kind of task, simply for the jist of it, of course tables, though despised, work quite well for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the method we went with was having one div, in which we added Labels having `float:left` and `width:50%`, controls with the same stats and afterwards a placeholder-span with `float:left` and `width:100%`. It looks like a table and is arranged like one, but doesn't have the disadvantages of actual tables.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a grid with one or two templates columns, and add the necessary control on RowDataBound event or RowCreated. I'm using the code below to activate one control in rowdatabound

```
  ((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtAutoEvaluare")).ReadOnly = false;
```

I think you can use to add controls in rowcreated event

```
            TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
        e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(t1);
```

Comment: Interesting approach, worth an upvote too, but I'm afraid the stress of having GridViews which then require an OnRowUpdating, OnDataBound, OnCancelingEdit, etc. -Event is rather nasty, + like this I can just pick out my Controls after submitting the Form like `dynamic ctrl = divRight.FindControl(controlName);`